# Open Layers 3 Icon overlap tearing

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector layer with a lot of close together data, each rendered by an icon. When rendered in Open Layers 3 using icons of any type/design I often get tearing of elements trying to get through others, I'm sure many people using Open Layers will have seen this happen.

Is there a way of solving this issue?

My code is fairly standard:

```
var styleCache2 = {};
var WFS_layer_Dangerous_Bends = new ol.layer.Vector({
source : new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    projection : 'EPSG:3857',
    url : "Vector_Data/A_Vector_Data_Set.geojson"
}),
style : function(feature, resolution) {

    if (!styleCache2[path]) {
        styleCache2[path] = [new ol.style.Style({
            fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                color : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
            }),
            stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                color : '#319FD3',
                width : 1
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    anchor: [x_anchor, y_anchor],
                    anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    src: path
                }))         

            }),
            zIndex : 1
        })];
    }
    return styleCache2[path];
}
});

/*Creating the map object linked to the map selector/div in the HTML */
map_object = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
controls: controls_list,
interactions: interactions_list,
overlays: [overlay],
layers: [OSM_raster, WFS_layer_Dangerous_Bends],
view: view
});
```

Obviously overlay, controls_list, interactions_list and the OSM_raster are defined somewhere too, but I don't think they're relevant to the question so I haven't included them.

I tried to capture an example, it's quite difficult because its intermittent, this shows about 5 icons overlapping normally, but a couple in the middle are tearing through each other:

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example on an image?

Comment: I have added a picture.  Apologies I didn't know this could be done until now.

Comment: Hi, I am first working on my OL3 project Tuesday. So I will return later, if you have not solved your problem before.